AWS SSM failing after implementing IP route over one interface
I have a EC2 instance in an autoscaling group that I add an extra network interface (ENI) to because I want it to have a static private IP address (By all means if someone has a tip to do this in a better way let me know as well!). To make sure all my outgoing traffic goes over that secondary I add a route with ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth1.
But this kills my current SSM session (using Ansible so this fails my full ansible playbook) and actually makes it impossible to reconnect using SSM again. And I am quite stuck on how to then correctly configure this to have a static IP but also keep SSM working.
SMALL EDIT: For private static IP in an ASG with only one instance it works to just set one specific network interface and accept the fact that creating a new one or an instance refresh fails a bunch of times first before succeeding and adding 10 minutes to your deployment.
